# Potential Energy of a Lagrangian System Involving a Mass and Spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, spring

[image: Question text]

[image: Figure]

If you were to calculate the potential energy term of the Lagrangian for this system, would there be an mg term included, or would it be unnecessary as the change in potential energy of the mass would be accounted for by the increase in potential energy of the spring? I would be grateful if anyone could advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seeems you are overthinking this problem.
The potential energy of the system has two components:

- potential energy of the mass $m$ due to gravity: $-mgx$
- potential energy of the spring due to compression/expansion: $\frac{1}{2}k(x-x_0)^2$,
  where $x_0$ is the equilibrium position of the spring
  if there would be no mass $m$ attached via the strap.

To get the total potential energy you need to add these two components.
There is no reason to assume that these two energies somehow compensate each other .

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is what I originally thought would be the case, but an online solution I saw for the Lagrangian of this system had no _mg_  term included. I had: $$L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{4}m_o\dot{x}^2 -(\frac{1}{2}kx^2 -mgx)$$ While the online solution had: $$L=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{4}m_o\dot{x}^2 -\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$ So the online solution I found is wrong then?

Comment: @Daire Yes, the online solution without the $mgx$ term looks wrong to me.